# Input leakage on digital input

Tags: gpio, leakage-current

I'm trying to understand precisely input leakage when a GPIO is configured as an input. So I read some MCU datasheets, here is [kinetis MK20 datasheets](http://www.nxp.com/assets/documents/data/en/data-sheets/K20P144M100SF2.pdf) 
on p15/16 are given input leakage currents.

I've also read [this document](http://www.ni.com/example/30949/en/) about input leakage measurements. First cause of input leakage are protection diodes.

Vil/Vih is maximum input voltage to read a low/high level on digital input. 
We can see, input leakage has maximum values when Vil < Vin < Vdd, in this case when Vdd=3.3V we get ~15µA input current.

- from [theory](http://www.ni.com/example/30949/en/) protection diodes are mostly responsible of leakage current, [here is a schottky diode datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/81/a4/1f/0e/ca/8c/47/ba/CD00012201/files/CD00012201.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00012201.pdf), in figure 4 is a reverse leakage current vs voltage figure. As you can see current increases with voltage. So, for MK20, when voltage Vil < Vin < Vdd, a current goes from input to GND threw reversed diode, its name is Iind. But, why do we have min leakage current when Vin = Vdd and much higher current when Vil < Vin < Vdd ?

In note (7)

> Examples calculated using Vil relation, Vdd, and max Iind :
>   Zind=Vil/Iind. This is the impedance needed to pull a high signal to a
>   level below Vil due to leakage when Vil < Vin < Vdd. These examples
>   assume signal source low = 0V

I'm not sure I've fully understood this note. When we apply Vil < Vin < Vdd, we can read on Input a low level. It means if we have Vil < Vin < Vdd, for example Vin = 3V applied with an output impedance of 100k on digital input, we will have a voltage divider on Input. So on Input we will have 3V x 50/(50 + 100) (voltage divider) = 1V => low logical level will be read.

- Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. Can you be concise? Also you talk about a schottky diode then, in the same sentence mention "Vil < Vin < Vdd" - what has this to do with that schottky diode?

Comment: Vil < Vin means that you might no longer read a low level.

Comment: This somewhat weird behavior appears to be a result of 5V-tolerant inputs- leakage through an internal Schottky or something similar.

Comment: @Andy aka, I've edited post to reformulate first question.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany , leakage is because of input protection leakage (also refer datasheet p41), but my question is why at Vdd, leakage decreases so much, when in theory it increases with voltage for a diode. As you said it must be because of Input 5.5V protection, because as we can see leakage current in this zone is 1µA (max 50µA) << leakage in Vil < Vin < Vdd zone. But, I would like to understand precisely how does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a precise [response](https://community.nxp.com/message/915940?commentID=915940#comment-915940) from NXP:

---

[image: screen capture from NXP community web page]